# Confused on Mathjax formula responsiveness

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, mathjax

This is the Mathjax component on Vue 2:

```js
<template>
  <div class="w=[100%]">
    <div
      ref="mathJaxEl"
      class="mathjax-container"
    >
      {{ formula }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'VueMathjax',
  props: {
    formula: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
    isLineBreak: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    },
    safe: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: true,
    },
    options: {
      type: Object,
      default: function () {
        return {};
      },
    },
  },
  created() {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.9/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS_HTML';
    document.head.appendChild(script);
  },
  mounted() {
    this.renderMathJax();
  },
  updated() {
    this.renderMathJax();
  },
  methods: {
    renderMathJax() {
      if (window.MathJax) {
        window.MathJax.Hub.Config({
          tex2jax: {
            inlineMath: [
              ['$', '$'],
              ['(', ')'],
            ],
            displayMath: [
              ['$$', '$$'],
              ['[', ']'],
            ],
            processEscapes: true,
            processEnvironments: true,
          },
          // displayAlign: 'center',
          'HTML-CSS': {
            //   styles: { '.MathJax_Display': { margin: 0 } },
            linebreaks: { automatic: this.isLineBreak },
          },
          ...this.options,
        });

        window.MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset', window.MathJax.Hub, this.$refs.mathJaxEl]);
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

The component is being passed the formula as shown on the image. [image]
So, I want the "abcdef" to wrap on 2 rows like "def" to align with the denominator and "abc" to align with the numerator of the fraction. Additionally, I also want the abcdef part to wrap randomly within 2 rows and not the rest of the formula when width is limited since it is a long text like instead of abc and def wrapping on different rows, it could be "ab" and "cdef".

I just can't get it done on Mathjax after a lot of tries. Any help would be greatly appreaciated. Thank you.